# How to solve the problem, if chartPanned Event is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, nativescript, gesture

(Nativescript 5.3, Angular)

I used the nativescript-ui-samples app to evaluate and test chart features for our app. (started with: chart-behaviors-pan-zoom.component)

It is required to move/pan the chart and then reload dependent on the movement other (more) values from previous time period.

My problem was to get any pan event inside the chart. Outside the chart for example on a label the pan event is working.

I have tried different possibilities to get the event, but none of them were working:

1. Tried to put the RadChartesianChart in a gridlayout to get the events

   Tried it with `isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` and `isPassThroughParentEnabled="true"` on the gridlayout
2. I have tried to call the following method in html on RadChartesianChart: method (chartPanned)="chartPanned()"
3. I have tried to call the folloing method in html on RadChartesianChart: method (chartPanned)="chartPanned()"
4. Tried the same as in number 2 and 3 with CategoricalAxis
5. Tried to register event in component ts file

TypeScript Code like described in number 5

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._categoricalSource = new ObservableArray(this._dataService.getCategoricalSource());

    const chart = this.theChart.nativeElement as RadCartesianChart;
    console.log('mychart');
    console.log(chart);

    // NOT working !!!
    chart.on(GestureTypes.pan, function () {
        console.log("chart Pan deltaX");
    });
    chart.on('chartPanned', function () {
        console.log("chartPanned Pan");
    });
    chart.on('chartPanFinishedEvent', function (args: PanGestureEventData) {
        console.log("chartPanned Pan deltaX:" + args.deltaX + "; deltaY:" + args.deltaY + ";");
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<RadCartesianChart row="1" #theChart tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton isUserInteractionEnabled="false" isPassThroughParentEnabled ="true">

    <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="categoricalSource" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="SecondVal">
        <LinearAxis tkBarVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Right" allowZoom="true" allowPan="false"></LinearAxis>
    </BarSeries>

    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="categoricalSource" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount">
        <LinearAxis tkLineVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Left" allowPan="false" allowZoom="true"></LinearAxis>
    </LineSeries>

    <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis allowPan="true" allowZoom="false"></CategoricalAxis>

</RadCartesianChart>
```

I expect to get the raised pan event if i pan in the chart ui.

Comment: It should be `chartPanFinished` instead of `chartPanFinishedEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't work for me.

I changed the `chartPanFinishedEvent` to `chartPanFinished`. 
(I also removed the flags in html `isUserInteractionEnabled` and  `isPassThroughParentEnabled .`)
Do you have any other idea?